# wOODy's Numerical Keyboard in VFP

Tags: keyboard, visual-foxpro, numerical

Can anybody help me to find wOOdy's numerical keyboard source files shown in below link ?

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/711db9ac-b785-45eb-b6ad-6aface9724b7/virtual-keyboard-by-woodys-visual-foxpro-code-snippets?forum=visualfoxprogeneral

I searched in google but could not locate the files, may be i am not fluent in German :-D

Answer (score 0):

The woody's links are broken and i cannot locate anywhere the post of virtual keyboard.
i have worked on this there is many years ago.
i send you below the flat code i adapted form the woody's virtual keyboard in only one prg-hope this helps you (my blog: http://yousfi.over-blog.com/)

```
*Begin code
                set safe off
        set defa to addbs(justpath(sys(16,1)))

        publi m.myvar1,m.myvar2,m.myvar3
        text to m.myvar1 noshow
        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
        endtext
        strtofile(strconv(m.myvar1,14),'img1.jpg')

        text to m.myvar2 noshow
        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
        endtext
        strtofile(strconv(m.myvar2,14),'img2.jpg')

        text to m.myvar3 noshow
        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
        endtext
        strtofile(strconv(m.myvar3,14),'img3.jpg')


        publi yform
        yform=newObject("asup")
        yform.show
        read events
        retu
        *
        DEFINE CLASS asup AS form
            Height = 222
            Width = 252
            AutoCenter = .T.
            Caption = "Sampleform for Virtual Keyboard"
            *-- Reference for the Keyboard
            okeyboard = .NULL.
            Name = "Form1"

            ADD OBJECT label1 AS label WITH ;
                AutoSize = .T., ;
                BackStyle = 0, ;
                Caption = "Enter Value:", ;
                Height = 17, ;
                Left = 24, ;
                Top = 36, ;
                Width = 68, ;
                Style = 3, ;
                Name = "Label1"

            ADD OBJECT text1 AS textbox WITH ;
                FontName = "Courier New", ;
                Alignment = 3, ;
                Value = 0, ;
                Height = 23, ;
                InputMask = "999,999.999", ;
                Left = 100, ;
                SelectOnEntry = .T., ;
                Top = 33, ;
                Width = 128, ;
                Name = "Text1"

            ADD OBJECT label2 AS label WITH ;
                AutoSize = .T., ;
                BackStyle = 0, ;
                Caption = "Enter Value:", ;
                Height = 17, ;
                Left = 25, ;
                Top = 68, ;
                Width = 68, ;
                Style = 3, ;
                Name = "Label2"

            ADD OBJECT text2 AS textbox WITH ;
                FontName = "Courier New", ;
                Alignment = 3, ;
                Value = 0, ;
                Height = 23, ;
                InputMask = "999,999.999", ;
                Left = 101, ;
                SelectOnEntry = .T., ;
                Top = 65, ;
                Width = 128, ;
                Name = "Text2"


            ADD OBJECT label3 AS label WITH ;
                AutoSize = .T., ;
                BackStyle = 0, ;
                Caption = "Enter Value:", ;
                Height = 17, ;
                Left = 25, ;
                Top = 99, ;
                Width = 68, ;
                Style = 3, ;
                Name = "Label3"

            ADD OBJECT text3 AS textbox WITH ;
                FontName = "Courier New", ;
                Alignment = 3, ;
                Value = 0, ;
                Height = 23, ;
                InputMask = "999,999.999", ;
                Left = 101, ;
                SelectOnEntry = .T., ;
                Top = 96, ;
                Width = 128, ;
                Name = "Text3"

            ADD OBJECT label4 AS label WITH ;
                AutoSize = .T., ;
                BackStyle = 0, ;
                Caption = "Enter Value:", ;
                Height = 17, ;
                Left = 26, ;
                Top = 131, ;
                Width = 68, ;
                Style = 3, ;
                Name = "Label4"

            ADD OBJECT text4 AS textbox WITH ;
                FontName = "Courier New", ;
                Alignment = 3, ;
                Value = 0, ;
                Height = 23, ;
                InputMask = "999,999.999", ;
                Left = 102, ;
                SelectOnEntry = .T., ;
                Top = 128, ;
                Width = 128, ;
                Name = "Text4"

            ADD OBJECT label5 AS label WITH ;
                AutoSize = .T., ;
                WordWrap = .T., ;
                Caption = "Here the additional OK Button closes the entry form", ;
                Height = 32, ;
                Left = 12, ;
                Top = 168, ;
                Width = 204, ;
                Name = "Label5"

            PROCEDURE Destroy
                ** Kill the Keyboard
                Thisform.okeyboard = .NULL.
            ENDPROC


            PROCEDURE Init
                 *
                * THISFORM.oKeyboard = NEWOBJECT("tlbNumKeyboard1")     &&uncomment to see another keybord....
                ** choose the one you like best
                THISFORM.oKeyboard = NEWOBJECT("tlbNumKeyboard2")    
                ** see also Form.Destroy for killig it

                WITH THISFORM.oKeyboard
                    .LEFT = THISFORM.LEFT + THISFORM.WIDTH && position to the right of form
                    .TOP = (_SCREEN.HEIGHT - .HEIGHT) /2
                    .VISIBLE = .T.
                ENDWITH
            ENDPROC


            PROCEDURE text1.LostFocus
                This.BackColor = RGB(255,255,255)
            ENDPROC


            PROCEDURE text1.GotFocus
                This.BackColor = RGB(255,128,255)
            ENDPROC

            PROCEDURE text2.GotFocus
                This.BackColor = RGB(255,128,255)
            ENDPROC

            PROCEDURE text2.LostFocus
                This.BackColor = RGB(255,255,255)
            ENDPROC

            PROCEDURE text3.GotFocus
                This.BackColor = RGB(255,128,255)
            ENDPROC

            PROCEDURE text3.LostFocus
                This.BackColor = RGB(255,255,255)
            ENDPROC

            PROCEDURE text4.GotFocus
                This.BackColor = RGB(255,128,255)
            ENDPROC

            PROCEDURE text4.LostFocus
                This.BackColor = RGB(255,255,255)
            ENDPROC

            Procedure destroy
            clea events
            endproc


        ENDDEFINE
        *
        *-- EndDefine: asup
        **************************************************
        *
        DEFINE CLASS cmdkeyboard AS commandbutton
            Height = 70
            Width = 70
            FontBold = .T.
            FontName = "Verdana"
            FontSize = 22
            Picture = "img1.jpg"    &&"images\rot02_70x70.jpg"
            Caption = "1"
            PicturePosition = 12
            Alignment = 2
            Name = "cmdkeyboard"


            PROCEDURE Click
                DO CASE
                CASE This.Caption ="C"
                    KEYBOARD "{BACKSPACE}"
                CASE This.Caption ="Space"
                    KEYBOARD " "
                CASE This.Caption ="<"
                    KEYBOARD "{LEFTARROW}"
                CASE This.Caption =">"
                    KEYBOARD "{RIGHTARROW}"
                CASE This.Caption = CHR(0xFC)   && this is the Ansicode of that WingDings symbols, See \Windows\CharMap.exe for those codes
                    KEYBOARD "{ENTER}"
                    ** Want to close the form?
                    _screen.ActiveForm.release() 

                CASE This.Caption = CHR(0xD9)
                    KEYBOARD "{UPARROW}"
                CASE This.Caption = CHR(0xDA)
                    KEYBOARD "{DNARROW}"    
                CASE This.Caption = "."
                    KEYBOARD SET("POINT")   && for international settings

                OTHERWISE
                    KEYBOARD This.Caption
                ENDCASE
            ENDPROC

        ENDDEFINE
        *
        *-- EndDefine: cmdkeyboard

        *
        DEFINE CLASS cntnumkeyboard1 AS container
            Width = 209
            Height = 278
            BackStyle = 0
            BorderWidth = 0
            Name = "cntnumkeyboard1"

            ADD OBJECT cmdkeyboard1 AS cmdkeyboard WITH ;
                Top = 0, ;
                Left = 0, ;
                Name = "Cmdkeyboard1"

            ADD OBJECT cmdkeyboard2 AS cmdkeyboard WITH ;
                Top = 0, ;
                Left = 69, ;
                Caption = "2", ;
                Name = "Cmdkeyboard2"

            ADD OBJECT cmdkeyboard3 AS cmdkeyboard WITH ;
                Top = 0, ;
                Left = 138, ;
                Caption = "3", ;
                Name = "Cmdkeyboard3"

            ADD OBJECT cmdkeyboard4 AS cmdkeyboard WITH ;
                Top = 69, ;
                Left = 0, ;
                Caption = "4", ;
                Name = "Cmdkeyboard4"

            ADD OBJECT cmdkeyboard5 AS cmdkeyboard WITH ;
                Top = 69, ;
                Left = 69, ;
                Caption = "5", ;
                Name = "Cmdkeyboard5"

            ADD OBJECT cmdkeyboard6 AS cmdkeyboard WITH ;
                Top = 69, ;
                Left = 138, ;
                Caption = "6", ;
                Name = "Cmdkeyboard6"

            ADD OBJECT cmdkeyboard7 AS cmdkeyboard WITH ;
                Top = 138, ;
                Left = 0, ;
                Caption = "7", ;
                Name = "Cmdkeyboard7"

            ADD OBJECT cmdkeyboard8 AS cmdkeyboard WITH ;
                Top = 138, ;
                Left = 69, ;
                Caption = "8", ;
                Name = "Cmdkeyboard8"

            ADD OBJECT cmdkeyboard9 AS cmdkeyboard WITH ;
                Top = 138, ;
                Left = 138, ;
                Caption = "9", ;
                Name = "Cmdkeyboard9"

            ADD OBJECT cmdkeyboard10 AS cmdkeyboard WITH ;
                Top = 207, ;
                Left = 0, ;
                Caption = ".", ;
                Name = "Cmdkeyboard10"

            ADD OBJECT cmdkeyboard11 AS cmdkeyboard WITH ;
                Top = 207, ;
                Left = 69, ;
                Caption = "0", ;
                Name = "Cmdkeyboard11"

            ADD OBJECT cmdkeyboard12 AS cmdkeyboard WITH ;
                Top = 207, ;
                Left = 138, ;
                Caption = "C", ;
                Name = "Cmdkeyboard12"
        ENDDEFINE
        *
        *-- EndDefine: cntnumkeyboard1

        *
        DEFINE CLASS cntnumkeyboard2 AS cntnumkeyboard1
            Width = 284
            Height = 279
            Name = "cntnumkeyboard2"
            Cmdkeyboard1.Name = "Cmdkeyboard1"
            Cmdkeyboard2.Name = "Cmdkeyboard2"
            Cmdkeyboard3.Name = "Cmdkeyboard3"
            Cmdkeyboard4.Name = "Cmdkeyboard4"
            Cmdkeyboard5.Name = "Cmdkeyboard5"
            Cmdkeyboard6.Name = "Cmdkeyboard6"
            Cmdkeyboard7.Name = "Cmdkeyboard7"
            Cmdkeyboard8.Name = "Cmdkeyboard8"
            Cmdkeyboard9.Name = "Cmdkeyboard9"
            Cmdkeyboard10.Name = "Cmdkeyboard10"
            Cmdkeyboard11.Name = "Cmdkeyboard11"
            Cmdkeyboard12.Name = "Cmdkeyboard12"

            ADD OBJECT cmdkeyboard13 AS cmdkeyboard WITH ;
                Top = 1, ;
                Left = 212, ;
                Height = 70, ;
                Width = 70, ;
                FontName = "Wingdings", ;
                Picture ="img2.jpg", ;
                Caption = "Ù", ;
                Name = "Cmdkeyboard13"

            ADD OBJECT cmdkeyboard14 AS cmdkeyboard WITH ;
                Top = 70, ;
                Left = 212, ;
                Height = 70, ;
                Width = 70, ;
                FontName = "Wingdings", ;
                Picture = "img2.jpg", ;
                Caption = "Ú", ;
                Name = "Cmdkeyboard14"

            ADD OBJECT cmdkeyboard15 AS cmdkeyboard WITH ;
                Top = 139, ;
                Left = 212, ;
                Height = 139, ;
                Width = 70, ;
                FontName = "Wingdings", ;
                FontSize = 34, ;
                Picture = "img2.jpg" , ;
                Caption = "ü", ;
                Name = "Cmdkeyboard15"

        ENDDEFINE
        *
        *-- EndDefine: cntnumkeyboard2
        **************************************************
        *
        DEFINE CLASS tlbnumkeyboard1 AS toolbar
            Caption = "Numeric Input"
            Height = 284
            Left = 0
            Top = 0
            Width = 219
            ControlBox = .F.
            Name = "tlbnumkeyboard1"

            ADD OBJECT cntnumkeyboard1 AS cntnumkeyboard1 WITH ;
                Top = 3, ;
                Left = 5, ;
                Name = "Cntnumkeyboard1", ;
                Cmdkeyboard1.Name = "Cmdkeyboard1", ;
                Cmdkeyboard2.Name = "Cmdkeyboard2", ;
                Cmdkeyboard3.Name = "Cmdkeyboard3", ;
                Cmdkeyboard4.Name = "Cmdkeyboard4", ;
                Cmdkeyboard5.Name = "Cmdkeyboard5", ;
                Cmdkeyboard6.Name = "Cmdkeyboard6", ;
                Cmdkeyboard7.Name = "Cmdkeyboard7", ;
                Cmdkeyboard8.Name = "Cmdkeyboard8", ;
                Cmdkeyboard9.Name = "Cmdkeyboard9", ;
                Cmdkeyboard10.Name = "Cmdkeyboard10", ;
                Cmdkeyboard11.Name = "Cmdkeyboard11", ;
                Cmdkeyboard12.Name = "Cmdkeyboard12"

        ENDDEFINE
        *
        *-- EndDefine: tlbnumkeyboard1
        *
        DEFINE CLASS tlbnumkeyboard2 AS toolbar
            Caption = "Numeric Input"
            Height = 285
            Left = 0
            Top = 0
            Width = 294
            ControlBox = .F.
            Name = "tlbnumkeyboard2"

            ADD OBJECT cntnumkeyboard21 AS cntnumkeyboard2 WITH ;
                Top = 3, ;
                Left = 5, ;
                Name = "Cntnumkeyboard21", ;
                Cmdkeyboard1.Name = "Cmdkeyboard1", ;
                Cmdkeyboard2.Name = "Cmdkeyboard2", ;
                Cmdkeyboard3.Name = "Cmdkeyboard3", ;
                Cmdkeyboard4.Name = "Cmdkeyboard4", ;
                Cmdkeyboard5.Name = "Cmdkeyboard5", ;
                Cmdkeyboard6.Name = "Cmdkeyboard6", ;
                Cmdkeyboard7.Name = "Cmdkeyboard7", ;
                Cmdkeyboard8.Name = "Cmdkeyboard8", ;
                Cmdkeyboard9.Name = "Cmdkeyboard9", ;
                Cmdkeyboard10.Name = "Cmdkeyboard10", ;
                Cmdkeyboard11.Name = "Cmdkeyboard11", ;
                Cmdkeyboard12.Name = "Cmdkeyboard12", ;
                Cmdkeyboard13.Name = "Cmdkeyboard13", ;
                Cmdkeyboard14.Name = "Cmdkeyboard14", ;
                Cmdkeyboard15.Name = "Cmdkeyboard15"

        ENDDEFINE
        *
        *-- EndDefine: tlbnumkeyboard2


*endcode
```

Comment: Dear Yousfi, I created a class with buttons and place them and create another class as a container for the keyboard. Now i used this class in a form. When i click on a button in keyboard while the mouse pointer is in a text box outside of the class but in a form. it didnt work.

Comment: I create a class according to your code,( a container with numbered buttons) But when i use the class as an object in main form i found an issue. If I press a numbered button while the cursor is outside the container the keyboard key is not working and the text box gets the value. Any idea ?

Comment: Yes if click out of the form ther is a focus problem.Can resolve this issue by putting the form model then it retains the focus all time.can simply change:yform.show(1)

Comment: (sorry problem with this editbox)---and cut read events in code.

Comment: Hi Yousfi, There is no read events in my code as i am running the form inside the application. Also the form also set as Model.

Comment: As i said,if you set form.windowtype=1 or make form.show(1)  the form is modal (..not model) and the focus cannot go away,its on the form only and you solve your problem.
read events is then for your application and dont needed here.